# how do I type && in latex?

Tags: latex

So i'm trying to make a table but it doesn't look to good since the lines break inside the table in a way I don't like.

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{8cm}|p{1cm}|}
\hline
! (4 < 5) &   \\ 
! false &   \\ 
(2 > 2) ││ ((4 == 4) && (1 < 0)) &   \\ 
(2 > 2) ││ (4 == 4) && (1 < 0) & \\
(34 != 33) && ! false & \\
\hline
end{tabular}
```

What happens is that it breaks into new lines after every "&&", how do I stop this from happening? How do I make latex type "&&" instead of it thinking "& something empty &"?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
(La)TeX-related questions are better asked at [tex.se]. Your question has been flagged so that it gets migrated there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an escape character: \
(I added a package here for clarity)

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{8cm}|p{1cm}|}
\hline
! (4 < 5) &   \\ 
! false &   \\ 
(2 > 2) ││ ((4 == 4) \&\& (1 < 0)) &   \\ 
(2 > 2) ││ (4 == 4) \&\& (1 < 0) & \\
(34 != 33) \&\& ! false & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```